# Не отображается дочерний компонент React.js

Tags: reactjs

В консоле ошибок нет, но браузер не отображает компонент SliderPage

```
function SliderPage() {
   return (
      <>
         <div className='SliderPage'>hello</div>
      </>
   );
}

function Slider() {
   return (
      <>
         <div className='Slider'></div>
      </>
   );
}

export default function App() {
   return (
      <>
         <Slider>
            <SliderPage />
         </Slider>
      </>
   );
}
```

Comment: Почему но должен его отображать, если компонент slider кроме чебя ничего не рендерит?

Comment: Извините не понял. Ответ наверное такой "Почему он должен его отображать, если компонент slider кроме себя ничего не рендерит?". Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый, использовать свойство children

```
function SliderPage() {
  return (
    <div className='SliderPage'>hello</div>
  );
}

function Slider({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className='Slider'>{ children }</div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Slider>
      <SliderPage />
    </Slider>
  );
}
```

Вариант второй:

```
function SliderPage() {
  return (
    <div className='SliderPage'>hello</div>
  );
}

function Slider() {
  return (
    <SliderPage/>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Slider />
  );
}
```